# How can I mirror one Synology DiskStation to another so as to use the other as a backup?

Tags: synology

Currently, I have a Synology DiskStation DS216 at my office. I bought new DiskStation DS218+ to replace the old one.

I want to set up DS218+ to  mirror  its data to DS216 as a backup so that in case by DS218+ fails I can have backup of my data.

Can anybody tell me the procedure to do something like this?

Comment: https://www.synology.com/en-us/dsm/packages/CloudStationClient

Comment: A more thorough solution has one of these off site with automated success reports.  Site to site VPN or similar would have to be set up in order to do it.

Answer (score 1):

The standard way to achieve this on a Synology NAS would be to use [Hyper Backup](https://www.synology.com/en-us/dsm/feature/hyper_backup). Setting it up is [pretty straightforward](https://synoguide.com/2017/12/01/create-a-hyper-backup-to-a-remote-synology/): just install Hyper Backup on source NAS, install Hyper Backup Vault on target NAS and configure backup target on the source. The drawback of this method is that backups are stored in proprietary format which can be browsed only with Hyper Backup Explorer.

I believe you could also convince Hyper Backup to mirror through WebDAV, that would actually create regular files on the target but it won't retain file history. It will basically be a distributed RAID1. So if ransomware encrypts your files, Synology will make sure all copies are encrypted ;) The regular Hyper Backup keeps file history, so it should save you in this case.